# writing to existing CSV file and saving its data

Tags: python

I'm creating a program for online shop and I have problems with rewriting on the csv file of the users registration. I create the file and put headers(as list of information that I want).
I'm having problem with adding the new users. Every time when I run the program, enter all the information for the user, the csv file rewrites the user.
Could you help? I've tried everything, but it doesn't work...
Here is the code.
Please excuse me, I'm new to programming :)

```
header = ['ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Date Registered', 'Password']

with open('users.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
f.close()

new_user = []
user_id = 0

print(f" Welcome to the new online shop! \n")
print(f" You will need registration to enter.\n If you don't have please enter 0. \n "
      f"If you already have - please enter 1.\n For ADMIN menu - please enter 9")

class UserId:

    def __init__(self, id_user, new_user_fn,
                 new_user_ln, new_user_em,
                 new_user_phone, _new_user_pas,
                 new_user_date_reg):
        self.id_user = id_user
        self.new_user_fn = new_user_fn
        self.new_user_ln = new_user_ln
        self.new_user_em = new_user_em
        self.new_user_phone = new_user_phone
        self.new_user_date_reg = new_user_date_reg
        self._new_user_pas = _new_user_pas


def user_registration():
    now = datetime.now()
    dt = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    print(f" Enter your First name: ")
    new_user_fn = str(input()).upper()
    print(f" Enter your Last name: ")
    new_user_ln = str(input()).upper()
    print(f" Enter your email: ")
    new_user_em = input().upper()
    print(f" Enter your phone number: ")
    new_user_phone = str(input())
    new_user_date_reg = dt
    print(f" Enter your password: ")
    new_user_pas = str(input())
    new_user.append(user_id + 1)
    new_user.append(new_user_fn)
    new_user.append(new_user_ln)
    new_user.append(new_user_em)
    new_user.append(new_user_phone)
    new_user.append(new_user_date_reg)
    new_user.append(new_user_pas)
    with open("users.csv", 'a+', newline="") as e:
        writer1 = csv.writer(e)
        writer1.writerow(new_user)
    e.close()
```

Comment: The first thing you do is create the file (open w), this will reset the file. If you want to append, create file only if it not exists.

Comment: I just remove the first part with opening csv, and it works now, but the ID is not changing, it still to be 1

Comment: You need to read the file at start to get last user_id. (If file does not exist create with header and set user_id=0)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is here

```
with open('users.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(header)
  f.close()
```

By using the 'w' you are telling the program to always create a new file.So you must use 'a' instead of 'w' as you want to append to a file and not overwrite it.

Also with `with open` you don't need to use f.close() as `with open` automaticaly closes and saves the file

So the code shoud look like this

```
with open('users.csv','a') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerow(header)
```

Comment: like this I'm adding new rows, but the rest of the code is not working, so I remove the first part with opening csv and it works, but now the ID in the first column is the same = 1.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is test if your file exists :

```
fileName = 'users.csv'
if not os.path.exists(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
```

Notes :

1- using ´with’ means you do not need to close the file. All cleaning is done when exiting the inner code

2- using variable for file name variable is good so you are sure to always use the same file name; and when you have to modify it, then do it in one place.

Comment: Thanks, everything works correct :)